# Gather interleaving matrix rows from processes

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I have a 8x8 matrix stored as `float*`, that, following some calculations, is decomposed in two 4x8 matrices, divided into two process, as follows:

Process 0:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Process 1:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

I just want to merge these two matrices in an only matrix, interleaving the rows in this way:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

I am trying various variants of `MPI_Vector`, `MPI_Gatherv` and some other solutions, but it seems a bit difficult for me to do it.

What can I do? I want to understand what is the way to do it, I don't think it is so hard, but I am really not obtaining any useful result...

---

**EDIT**
Here is some code showing what I am trying to do to obtain this:

```
    MPI_Datatype dt;
    int gsizes[2], distribs[2], dargs[2], psizes[2];
    
    // original 4x8 submatrices
    gsizes[0] = 4;
    gsizes[1] = 8;

    distribs[0] = MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC;
    distribs[1] = MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC;

    // I want to interleave 2x8 blocks
    dargs[0] = 2;
    dargs[1] = 8;

    psizes[0] = 2; 
    psizes[1] = 1; // I just want 1 proc to have all the row

    MPI_Type_vector(2, 2 * 8, 1, MPI_FLOAT, &dt);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(dt, 0, 2*8*sizeof(float), &dt);
    MPI_Type_commit(&dt);

    int displs[2] = {0, 0};
    int recva[2] = {2, 2}; // I want to receive two 2*8 blocks from each process

    // src and result are two properly-allocated float*
    MPI_Gatherv(src, 4 * 8, MPI_FLOAT,
                result, recva, displs, dt, 0, group_comm);
```

The result is that only 17 out of 64 floats are received, only from the process 1, and in a scrambled order.

Please tell me if anything else is needed, I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Please share the code you've got so far, tell us how it fails or give the current output, and we can surely help you better.

Comment: Tagged the question with ```C``` and did not show any code that others can look at your efforts so far.

Comment: Create one receive datatype that is for four out of eight rows, resize it to the size of a single row and gather. note if you use Open MPI, you might also want to create a send datatype that describes the full 4x8 matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I apologize for the not completeness of my question. I have updated it with some code, please tell me if anything else is missing/required.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (that can be ran) and read again my previous comments. `displs` and `recva` look pretty obviously wrong.